# How to set timeout option for idtoken.NewClient

Tags: go

I'm using googles `idtoken.NewClient` to get some information from my gcp. I need to set a timeout because the request takes too long. I tried to set it up like this

```
        Timeout: time.Second * 10,
        Transport: http.DefaultTransport,
    }

    options := idtoken.WithHTTPClient(netClient)

    // client is a http.Client that automatically adds an "Authorization" header
    // to any requests made.
    client, err := idtoken.NewClient(ctx, targetURL, options)
```

but I am getting theq follwoing error:
`idtoken.NewClient: transport/http: WithHTTPClient passed to NewTransport`

I don't know how to set this option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a function accepts context, it's expected to handle its cancellation gracefully. That means, you can wrap the context with [`WithTimeout`](https://pkg.go.dev/context#WithTimeout), so that it will get cancelled after the given duration of time, e.g.:

```
timeout, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, 10 * time.Second)
defer cancel()
client, err := idtoken.NewClient(timeout, targetURL, options))
```

Comment: If i do it that way, the client still has a timeout of 0. And I still had to remove the options because of the error that it's throwing

Comment: But also, the content-length of the response header is `-1` this seems strange